# MVEL operator overloading

Tags: java, overloading, mvel

MVEL makes it very easy to provide custom functions to the parser context, but it's not clear whether there is an 'official' way to overload how the operators are evaluated. I have two specific use cases in mind:

- Performing arithmetic on an array should map the operation onto each element of the array, such that:

  `[1, 2, 3] + 1 == [2, 3, 4]`
- Any operation with a null operand should evaluate to null (like `#N/A` in Excel), such that:

  `1 + null == null`

If there is no 'official' solution to this, is there an obvious way to hack into MVEL to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

For 2nd issue

```
1+ null == null
```

or `1* null`

If you actually debug this in Mvel API classes, they are explicitly returning `false` or `1null` for this particular case.

If Mvel can fix this, it will be good. But this same issue i also encountered, so what we did, we created some intelligence before executing the expression, we modified the expression and included "IF" condition to check for the fields that are null and having operator as "/" or "*", the return null.

Also you can make use of `VariableResolverFactory`, and pass your function like below

```
 private static VariableResolverFactory getMvelFactory(Map contextMap) {
        VariableResolverFactory functionFactory = new MapVariableResolverFactory(contextMap);
        MVEL.eval("checkNullValue = def (x) { x == null ? 0 : x };", functionFactory);

        return functionFactory;
    }
```

So through this you can modify your executable expressions as below and return whatever values. Basically need to write a wrapper on top of MVEL.

`a + b` to `checkNullValue(a) + checkNullValue(b)`